# 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 - Xcode - Си

Tags: c, xcode, include

Как я понял проблема в 7 перменных которые я обьявляю в `x.h` файле, и инициализирую в файле `x.c`.

Не понимаю как решить эту проблему.

Возможно ошибка возникает также потому что я написал строку `#include "x.h"` и в `main.c`.

Comment: Код приведите в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь объявить для каждого юнита трансляции одинаковые переменные, то вам стоит добавлять ключевое слово `static` для каждой из этих переменных.

```
// A.c
static int a = 10; // изменение данной переменной никак не повлияет на переменную в B.h

// B.c
static int a = 15; // изменение данной переменной никак не повлияет на переменную в A.h

...
```

Если же вам просто нужны глобальные переменные да еще и так что бы их можно было использовать из разных юнитов трансляции, то вам поможет ключевое слово `extern`.

```
// A.c
int a = 10; // изменение данной переменной повлияет на переменную в B.h

// B.c
extern int a; // изменение данной переменной повлияет на переменную в A.h

...
```

Но имейте ввиду, при объявлении переменной с ключевым словом `extern`, при сборке юнитов трансляции в объектный файл, вы можете не получить ошибок, но вот на этапе компоновки *(линковки)*, если вдруг обнаружится что нет объявлений переменной с именем `a`, то вы получите ошибку, т.к. не будет найден ни один юнит трансляции в котором есть такая глобальная переменная.

P.S. вы все так же будете получать ошибки компоновки если снова где нибудь в двух и более местах объявите глобальную переменную с таким же именем, без ключевого слова `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

Объявляйте свои определения внутри условий

```
/* Такой заголовочник можно подлючать сколько хотите раз */

#ifndef MYDEF  /* условие: не определено ли MYDEF */
#define MYDEF /* Определяем определение MYDEF */
   /* дальше идут определения ваших переменных */
   int i;
#else
   /* этот блок необязательный */
#endif
```

Comment: Пока тс не покажет свой код, это ему ничем не поможет, скорее всего ему просто нужно ключевое слово static

Comment: @mik.ov Вряд ли - тогда в каждом файле будут свои переменные. Думаю, ему нужны `extern`.

Comment: @mik.ov , да требовалось static, но почему не понятно, можете дать ответ основываясь на этом?